# Android: How to create a custom array Adapter to show two textviews from database

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-arrayadapter

I need help in showing two values from database in my listview which I am populating through array Adapter but default array Adapter shows only 1 value I want to show two values. Below is my code of how i am populating the array adapter through db.

```
 private void updateUI() {
    ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    final Cursor cursor = db.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID, TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE},
            null, null, null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE);
        taskList.add(cursor.getString(idx));
    }

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                R.layout.item_todo,
                R.id.task_title,
                taskList);
        mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Use a model class array for that

Comment: post your adapter class code

Comment: first, do not use any `ArrayAdapter`, use `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead and your code will reduce to 5-10 simple lines ...

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code :**

```
  private void updateUI() {
        ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        final Cursor cursor = db.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
                new String[]{TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID, TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE},
                null, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.getCount()>0 && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
           int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE);
        taskList.add(cursor.getString(idx));
        }
    }

            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    R.layout.item_todo,
                    R.id.task_title,
                    taskList);
            mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
```